Unable to figure out what this part of the code is
In Logical Vectors chapter in r4ds.hadley.nz, the authors talk about logical subsetting and give the following code.
# Required packages
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)

flights |> 
  group_by(year, month, day) |> 
  summarize(
    behind = mean(arr_delay[arr_delay > 0], na.rm = TRUE),
    n = n(),
    .groups = "drop"
  )

This gives the average delay just for flights that were actually delayed.
However, I was curious on what would happen with a slight modification and ran the following code.
# Required packages
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)

flights |> 
 group_by(year, month, day) |> 
 filter(!is.na(arr_delay)) |> 
  summarize(
      behind = mean(arr_delay > 0)
 )

I understand that both are not the same, but I failed to figure out what the second code is throwing up. Thanks in advance for the help!

mean(arr_delay > 0) gives the proportion of delays that are larger than 0. The comparison operator returns a logical vector but the mean function expects numeric input. R coerces the data type from logical (FALSE, TRUE) to numeric (0, 1). So, sum would return the number of TRUE values and mean just divides by the number of all values.

To examine intermediate results along a pipe (and find up what the code is throwing up), you might find the "tee pipe" %T>% convenient. Example: flights |> step_A() %T>% print() |> step_B %T>% print() |> step_C will print the results of steps A-B before handing them over to the following step.

Also consider the difference between a delay of zero and a missing delay. A delay of zero means we know the flight was on time. A missing delay means we don’t know if the flight was delayed and, if it was, by how long.

@I_O, print() should always return input value invisibly, so it justworks(tm) with base pipe as well,  flights |> step_A() |> print() |> step_B() |> print() |> step_C()

You don’t describe what you got but my guess is that you got a bunch of 1 values. The mean of a vector of 1’s will be 1. You got rid of all the NAs and zeroes and were left with a bunch of 1’s.

@I_O  I'd be really careful about mixing base pipes and magrittr pipes!
